# Is it faster to return early or to let the code finish?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, return

If I have a method that contains a lot of if else statements, for example:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    if(..)
    else if(..)
    else if(...)
    else if(...)
    else if(...)

    //and so on            
}
```

Would it be faster to place return inside these statements, so that the rest of the code is not checked after one statement is found true, or would it be faster to let the compiler hit the end bracket?

I guess it comes down to the question: Is the return statement efficient or not?

EDIT: The point of the question: Say you have a game loop that is constantly running, with code that holds a lot of methods and 'else ifs'. If I have to update 2000 different objects 60 times a second, that's 120000 'else ifs' checked (at the minimum) per second. So the answer to the question could potentially make a difference over time.

Comment: The `else` part *ensures* that "the rest of the code is not checked" once a match is found. If you omit the `else`, then you have a real question.

Comment: As I stated below, I'm wondering about the time it takes to skip the lines that are not checked, whereas a return might be able to avoid finding the end of the line and moving on right then and there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't matter.
Any sane or insane compiler will produce identical bytecode for either option.  (assuming that the code you write is actually equivalent)

You should use whichever approach is more readable.

Answer (score 12):

SLaks' answer is of course correct. But I think the fact that you are asking the question at all shows that you have a misunderstanding about what if-else means.  When you say

```
if(x) X();
else if(y) Y();
else if(z) Z();
return;
```

That means exactly the same thing as

```
if(x)
{
  X();
}
else
{
  if (y)
  {
    Y();
  }
  else
  {
    if (z)
    {
      Z();
    }
  }
}
return;
```

If, say, branch `x` is taken then `y` is never checked; control jumps straight to the `return` after `X()`.

In fact, there is no such thing as an "else if" in C# -- or C, C++, Java or JavaScript for that matter. There's just "else"; if you happen to put an `if` statement after the `else`, that's your business.  There's no "else if" any more than this

```
if (x) X();
else while(y) Y();
```

is an "else while" statement. You can put any statement you want after an `else`; most people choose to put an `if` or a block statement, but you can put any statement there you like.(*)

### UPDATE:

> I understand that the else if 'skips', the point of the question was would adding a return make it jump straight out, without taking the time to skip them in the first place. For example, at an extreme, one million if else statements in a row. It still needs to find the end of the line (which could take time). Am I right?

OK, we need to go to an even lower level. An `if-else` statement is compiled like this:

```
if (condition) 
    Consequence() 
else 
    Alternative();
Continuation();
```

is actually transformed into a series of goto statements:

```
if (!condition) 
    goto ALTERNATIVE;
Consequence();
goto CONTINUATION;
ALTERNATIVE:  Alternative();
CONTINUATION: Continuation();
```

So if you have

```
if (x) X(); 
else if (y) Y();
else if (z) Z();
return;
```

that first becomes

```
if (x)
    X(); 
else 
{
    if (y)
        Y();
    else
    {
        if (z)
            Z();
    }
}
```

which then becomes

```
if (!x) goto XALTERNATIVE;
X(); 
goto CONTINUATION;
XALTERNATIVE: if (!y) goto YALTERNATIVE;
Y();
goto CONTINUATION;
YALTERNATIVE: if (!z) goto CONTINUATION;
Z();
CONTINUATION: return;
```

Does that answer your question?

---

(*) Except a local declaration; C# forbids that.

Comment: You're right; I missed the part about the rest of the code not being checked.  This is a very important point to clarify.

Comment: I understand that the else if 'skips', the point of the question was would adding a return make it jump straight out, without taking the time to skip them in the first place. For example, at an extreme, one million if else statements in a row. It still needs to find the end of the line (which could take time). Am I right?

Comment: @Colton: I've updated my answer to address your new question. The short answer is no, it doesn't matter how many "ifs" there are in a row; finding the "return" is still just a "goto".

Comment: @Colton: Also, two things about performance. First, if you want to know which of two things is faster, **write it both ways, get out a stopwatch, run it both ways, and then you'll know which is faster**.  Don't ask strangers on the internet which is faster; you can easily find out for yourself. Second, you are asking about what would be an optimization that would save a couple nanoseconds at best. I assure you, you have bigger problems you could be worrying about.  Use a profiler to find the slow spots and concentrate on them.

Answer (score 0):

It is efficient when used as a guard for conditions, but in your case it would not matter, because once one of those statements is executed the others are not verified, but if you were doing something like this:

```
if(...){return;}
if(...){return;}
if(...){return;}
if(...){return;}
if(...){return;}
```

Then it would matter.

Comment: Yup! That is why I specified if else statements.

Comment: Then you're grand, there are no benefits there, but as a general case, guard conditions with return statements are better and more readable.

Comment: @svick, I updated the answer so it becomes a bit more c# like.